# GPO Screensaver not appearing

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows, active-directory, group-policy

I've got a small network that consists of 80+ workstations that are a mix of Win7 and XP. Recently I tried applying a branded screensaver to appear on all the computers after the predetermined(15 minutes) idle time. All the normal screensaver settings in GPO are set properly, and the *.scr file being copied correctly to the Windows\System32 directory when users logon(if they don't already have it).

When the allotted time frame passes, the computers simply lock themselves and the screen goes blank.

I've scoured Google and all the solutions I have found pertain to incorrect GPO policy or wrong files names, both of which I have ruled out. RSOP shows that the policy is correctly applied, and the file is being copied to the correct location.

Comment: Are the permissions on the screensaver file correct?

Comment: Maybe an issue with 32/64-bitness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out...feeling stupid though. Turns out that we had no power management in our GPO, and I assumed the best case. Turns out that by default the monitors were simply going to sleep before the screensaver would activate. I added a policy for monitor turnoff at 30 minutes and left the screensaver at 15 minutes...problem solved.

No wonder I hadn't found this particular answer on Google.

Comment: Awesome, glad you were able to figure it out.